# MVC viewmodel Edit shows nothing after Httppost

Tags: asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I've had issues with viewmodels for a while and I'd like to clear something up. In my viewmodel, I can show "index" and I can add a new employee "create", but the "Edit" doesn't work.

I can show the "edit" page, do my edits (like changing the Name) but when I post back, all the data shows up as **null**. In the "create", after I post the insert, the controller DOES SHOW the changes (EmployeeViewModel) and inserts the record. It just doesn't show when a do the "edit".

Is this something inherent in viewmodel's or is there something else?

Here's my viewmodel class (database first):

```
public partial class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }

        public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
    }

 public partial class Department
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Department()
        {
            this.Employees = new HashSet<Employee>();
        }

        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public string DepartmentName { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    }

  public class EmployeeViewModel
    {
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string DepartmentName { get; set; }

    }
```

Here's my controller:

```
public class TestController : Controller
    {
        public  db dContext = new db();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<Employee> employeelist = dContext.Employees.ToList();
            EmployeeViewModel employeeVM = new EmployeeViewModel();

            List<EmployeeViewModel> employeeVMList = employeelist.Select(x => new EmployeeViewModel
            {
                Name = x.Name,
                EmployeeId = x.EmployeeId,
                Address = x.Address,
                DepartmentId = x.DepartmentId,
                DepartmentName = x.Department.DepartmentName
            }).ToList();
            return View(employeeVMList);    
        }
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create( EmployeeViewModel employeeVM)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Employee e = new Employee();
                e.EmployeeId = employeeVM.EmployeeId;
                e.Name = employeeVM.Name;
                e.DepartmentId = employeeVM.DepartmentId;
                e.Address = employeeVM.Address;

                dContext.Employees.Add(e);
                dContext.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View("Index");
        } 

        public ActionResult Edit( EmployeeViewModel em , int? id)
        {
            var dbEmpVM = (from e in dContext.Employees
                           join d in dContext.Departments
                           on e.DepartmentId equals d.DepartmentId
                           where e.EmployeeId == id
                           select new EmployeeViewModel
                           {
                               EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId,
                               DepartmentId=e.DepartmentId,
                               Address=e.Address,
                               Name=e.Name,
                               DepartmentName=d.DepartmentName
                           }).ToList();      
             return View( dbEmpVM  );
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(EmployeeViewModel model, int id)
        {
            string name = Request.Form["EmployeeId"];
            string naaanm = model.EmployeeId.ToString();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
```

And here's my Edit:

```
@model  IEnumerable<MVCTutorial.Models.EmployeeViewModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}
<h4>(EmployeeViewModel)</h4>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor( i => item.EmployeeId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(i => item.EmployeeId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => item.EmployeeId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(i => item.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(i => item.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => item.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(i => item.DepartmentId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(i => item.DepartmentId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => item.DepartmentId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(i => item.DepartmentName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(i => item.DepartmentName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => item.DepartmentName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(i => item.Address, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(i => item.Address, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => item.Address, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    }
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" value="Edit" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</div>
} 
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

[EmployeeViewModel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SODyD.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code(in the edit view) will generate input markup like below.

```
<input class="form-control text-box single-line" 
        id="item_DepartmentName" name="item.DepartmentName" type="text" value="SomeName" />
```

See the name attribute value. It is `"item.DepartmentName"`. Your HttpPost action method parameter is the `EmployeeViewModel` type which does not have a property with this name! So model binder will not be able to map the form data posted from your form with this name (`"item.DepartmentName"`) to any properties of your method parameter.

The solution is to update your input field's **name** attribute value to match with the property names of your `EmployeeViewModel`. Ideally your code should generate markup like below.

```
<input name="DepartmentName" type="text" value="Some value" />
```

You can explcitily specify the `name` attribute alue when calling the html helpers. For example, with the `Html.TextBoxFor` helper

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(i => item.DepartmentName, 
                               new  { @class = "form-control", NAME = "DepartmentName"  })
```

Now when you submit the form, Model binder will be able to map the value of this form field to the `DepartmentName` property of your `EmployeeViewModel` object.

Comment: Shyju-thanks for the response. I'm still lost, though. The DepartmentName looks fine to me. Is there something else I'm missing? Do I have to change it to "TextBoxFor" ..rather than "EditorFor" because it's a different class (Department) ?

Comment: If you simply want input field for user to enter, use `TextBoXFor` helper method.

Comment: I changed the line to Html.TextBoxFor(i => item.DepartmentName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } }) .   It still shows null. Is there something else wrong?

Comment: You are using the second parameter wrong! Use it like how i have in the answer ( there is no 2 new anonymous objects)